# Does FreeBSD support network virtualization like Crossbow?

Tags: networking, freebsd, virtualization

Does FreeBSD support network virtualization like [Solaris Crossbow](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+crossbow/)?

I've tried to follow the VImage links from the FreeBSD [wiki page](http://wiki.freebsd.org/NetworkVirtualization), but the links are mostly dead.

If VImage is no longer part of FreeBSD, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, link to wiki seems dead, I am trying to see if we can get it up. But afaik, VImage is available and working in FreeBSD. Here are some links showing how to set it up:

http://wiki.polymorf.fr/index.php/Howto:FreeBSD_jail_vnet

http://bsdbased.com/2009/12/06/freebsd-8-vimage-epair-howto

http://tech.poojanblog.com/blog/unix-linux/set-up-vimagevnet-jail-on-freebsd-8-2/

Also, what version of FreeBSD are you working with?

Please let me know your specific usecase.

Comment: I'm not working with a particular version of FreeBSD. I'm just trying to understand what standard functionality is available in the core production FreeBSD versions now and what will be available in the future.

Comment: vimage is very unreliable at the moment though. Tear down a jail and the system will eventually crash due to memory leaks and/or pf related crashes. This is my experience with vimage on freebsd 9 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is an initiative to get OpenStack working in FreeBSD and this solution requires a software-defined networking (SDN) layer. Based on the FreeBSD [Project page](http://www.freebsd.org/news/status/report-2013-10-2013-12.html#FreeBSD-Host-Support-for-OpenStack-and-OpenContrail), the team at Semihalf.com are porting over Juniper's SDN sub-system.

[GitHub Project](https://github.com/Semihalf/contrail-vrouter). (as of 2020 no updates in 6 years)

For those who are not aware, Juniper has used a fork of FreeBSD for many years although I understand that they are a couple versions back.

Even more cool stuff is coming to FreeBSD :)

Comment: [Juniper Contrail PDF](http://www.juniper.net/us/en/local/pdf/whitepapers/2000535-en.pdf)

Comment: Just found the OpenContrail site: http://opencontrail.org/